# Git fetch / rebase / push sequence

Tags: git, github

It had been my understanding that to properly integrate trunk changes before pushing local commits the following would be the workflow:

1. git checkout
2. get fetch -a
3. git rebase origin
4. git push origin

The above sequence assumes there were no merge conflicts (which is my case).

But in any case that process did not completely succeeed:

1) checkout the branch ..

```
$git checkout coresql
Already on 'coresql'
```

2)  fetch works ..

```
17:11:40/ysgood $git fetch -a
remote: Counting objects: 24, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 24 (delta 5), reused 23 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (24/24), done.
From jgithub:/Mycompany/ys
   548347b..4975c4f  coresql    -> origin/coresql
```

3) rebase does ***not*** do the correct thing: there are changes in trunk that are not being reflected here (?)

```
17:11:51/ysgood $git rebase origin coresql
Already on 'coresql'
Current branch coresql is up to date.
```

4) So then naturally *push* fails given that the trunk changes were not properly integrated into the local

```
17:12:23/ysgood $git push origin coresql
To git@jgithub:/ThirdEyeCSS/yardstick-spark
 ! [rejected]        coresql -> coresql (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@jgithub:/Mycompany/ys'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So why would the git fetch -a / git rebase not have worked properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rebase` expects branch, not remote:

```
git rebase origin/coresql
```

If you use two-argument version of rebase, it specifies from which branch and to which branch to rebase, basically doing `git checkout SECOND && git rebase FIRST`.

You can also use `git pull --rebase origin coresql` instead of `fetch` + `rebase`.

Comment: I can NOT keep track of when to use repo/branch and when repo branch. any hints?

Comment: @javadba `remote branch` is for commands that contact the remote (`pull`, `push` and `fetch`), `remote/branch` for commands using local cache.